# imagemagick libMagickCore.so.2 not found

Tags: debian, imagemagick

I have 2 debian servers we use at work, one is our development server and the other is our production.  I am trying to get imagemagick working on both servers, and for some reason the production server is running imagemagick fine, but the dev server doesnt' seem to want to.

On both servers I typed

```
convert --version
```

and got this response in return

**PRODUCTION:**

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.6.0-4 2012-04-24 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2010 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

**DEVELOPMENT:**

```
convert: error while loading shared libraries: libMagickCore.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I did a dpkg against both servers to check versions and I got the following

**PRODUCTION:**

```
ii  imagemagick                         8:6.6.0.4-3+squeeze2         image manipulation programs
ii  libmagickcore3                      8:6.6.0.4-3+squeeze2         low-level image manipulation library
ii  libmagickcore3-extra                8:6.6.0.4-3+squeeze2         low-level image manipulation library - extra codecs
ii  libmagickwand3                      8:6.6.0.4-3+squeeze2         image manipulation library
ii  php5-imagick                        3.0.0~rc1-1                  ImageMagick module for php5
```

**DEVELOPMENT:**

```
ii  imagemagick                         8:6.6.0.4-3+squeeze2         image manipulation programs
ii  libmagickcore3                      8:6.6.0.4-3+squeeze2         low-level image manipulation library
ii  libmagickcore3-extra                8:6.6.0.4-3+squeeze2         low-level image manipulation library - extra codecs
ii  libmagickwand3                      8:6.6.0.4-3+squeeze2         image manipulation library
ii  php5-imagick                        3.0.0~rc1-1                  ImageMagick module for php5
```

I looked all over the OS for libMagickCore.so.2 and could never find it, I did find these files on both servers.

**PRODUCTION:**

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    22 May  2 14:32 libMagickCore.so.3 -> libMagickCore.so.3.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  2.3M Apr 24 15:44 libMagickCore.so.3.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    22 May  2 14:32 libMagickWand.so.3 -> libMagickWand.so.3.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1.1M Apr 24 15:44 libMagickWand.so.3.0.0
```

**DEVELOPMENT:**

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    22 May  2 14:35 libMagickCore.so.2 -> libMagickCore.so.3.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    22 May  2 14:30 libMagickCore.so.3 -> libMagickCore.so.3.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  2.3M Apr 24 15:44 libMagickCore.so.3.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    22 May  2 14:30 libMagickWand.so.3 -> libMagickWand.so.3.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1.1M Apr 24 15:44 libMagickWand.so.3.0.0
```

I manually added in the libMagickCore.so.2 onto the dev server to see if that would work, but it didn't.

I purged all of imagemagick from the dev server and reinstalled it and still nothing.  I ran ldconfig, and it will create links for version 3 but not 2.  I've even rebooted the machine, did updates/upgrades on both machines, and I'm just out of options of what to do.  Anyone out there have another idea for me?

Thanks a million!

**-- EDIT --**

Running the command

```
which convert
```

produced these outputs

**PRODUCTION**

```
/usr/bin/convert
```

**DEVELOPMENT**

```
/usr/local/bin/convert
```

So ... that ended up being my problem ... I removed the convert in /usr/local/bin off of my development server and it worked after that.

Comment: Can you add the output from `which convert` please?

Comment: ablackhat, add that as an answer and I'll accept it, you saved me enumorous amounts of frustratingly crappy hours!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm glad you solved the issue. To help others in a similar situation I'll just leave this here:

To find the library locally:

```
# updatedb
# locate libMagickCore
```

To find the library from the package manager:

```
# apt-file search  libMagickCore
```

To find if your library can be found by the system (is it in path)

```
# ldconfig -p | grep -i nameoflibrary
```

If your library is not on the list, but is on the system you can add it:

```
# ldconfig -n /path/toyournew/library/
```

Add it permanently to the path:

```
# /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf
```

This should be enough to solve this type of problem in the future no matter the library.

Comment: Thanks for this. In case it trips someone else up: if you edit `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf` manually, you then need to run `sudo ldconfig ` for the edit to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I took the advice from ablackhat and did `which convert` this showed me that my development server was looking in /usr/local/bin for the convert executable.  I deleted the executable from that directory and running `which convert` after that showed that my server was now using the executable in /usr/bin.  When I ran `convert --version` off of the /usr/bin/convert everything worked as hoped.